# Cordova webview lost wifi connection on Android 8.0 when running in background

Tags: android, cordova

I have a cordova app that need to keep connection even when running in background (lock screen). I used the battery wake lock for Android.
I tested on Android 5.0/7.0, it is OK. But on Samsung J7 (Android 8.0) this not works.

I use some log tools, and find the java native code has wifi connection, but the webview doesn't has wifi connection. It is quit strange.

(The webview is used to host a web socket connection)

Comment: I have the same issue with Chromium WebView on Android 10

Answer (score -1):

I just have a workaround for this problem. I play an audio every 30 seconds in the webview (html5 audio) when my app running in background. The audio is a blank audio(https://github.com/anars/blank-audio), and encoded into base64 as an offline audio.